# In production Vuetify inputs are white on hover but not when on local

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3

On
[local the active input field is fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKyLe.png) but in
[production active input field is white.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWPu9.png)

When using vuetify the text input fields are fine locally but when I push to production the fields go white when active. You can see at https://www.rehop.com.au/post

I am using Nuxt v3. This is waht the plugin file looks.

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    theme: { dark: true }
  })

  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

and my nuxt config file

```
export default {
  css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', 'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'],
  buildModules: [],
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', '@nuxtjs/dotenv'],
  target: 'static',
  imports: {
    autoImport: true
  },
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  vite: {
    define: {
      'process.env.DEBUG': false,
    },
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      SUPABASE_KEY: process.env.SUPABASE_KEY,
      SUPABASE_URL: process.env.SUPABASE_URL,
      IS_TEST: process.env.IS_TEST,
    }
  },
};
```

I tried changing variables in the styles section of the developer tools but was not able to find the cause.

Comment: The issue is on `<div class="v-field__overlay">` which is an element nested within your v-text-fields.  it has a value of `opacity: calc(var(--v-theme-overlay-multiplier)*.08);` and in your case the inspector says `--v-theme-overlay-multiplier is not set`.  It's supposed to be 1 by default but for you is 0 since it's not set.  I'm not sure why yours would be like that.  Are you on the latest Vuetify v3.0.x?  Paste your `nuxt.config.ts` and any relevant custom vuetify style files

Comment: @yoduh added my nuxt config above.  I'm on the latest v3.0.7 as of now with errors still occurring.

Comment: Vuetify explicitly sets `background-color: transparent; border-style: none;` for INPUT, BUTTON, SELECT and TEXTAREA. There is no such CSS definition on your production server - so some CSS is probably not included in the final bundle or you are including some CSS reset/normalize that breaks/overrides the Vuetify styling.

Answer (score 0):

By switching the label variant to solo this was fixed.